# Problem with new Marshmallow 6.1 on Samsung J5

Tags: facebook-messenger

the Facebook Messenger app & Whatsapp audio & video calling is not unavailable, it wants the access for camera & microphone, when the settings come I do it but it doesn't work, what to do?

[image: After clicking audio or video call on messenger screen]
<sup>After clicking audio or video call on messenger screen</sup>

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please see: [“Screen overlay detected” dialog?](/q/126798/16575), [Screen Overlay Detected, Permission problem](/q/159697/16575) and [all the other similar posts](/search?q=screen+overlay+answers%3A1).

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete and reinstall the application, id don't work try to reset the phone